# MySQL Update or Insert when columns match

Tags: mysql, if-statement, insert

I currently have the problem that i need to either insert or update a row when two columns(event_id and question_id) have the same value as another row
For example i have event 1 and question 2 of the event
Now when there is already an inserted entry it should update this one to the new value (selected)

But the syntax I tryed isn't working.Could you please help me with this problem?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id as @info FROM votes WHERE event_id = 1 AND question_id = 2)
  UPDATE votes SET selected='1,2,3' WHERE id=@info
ELSE
  INSERT INTO `votes` (`id`, `event_id`, `question_id`, `selected`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL,      1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: The Problem is that event_id  and question_id are neither UNIQUE nor a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: From your question, it seems like event_id and question_id together would be unique -- would they not be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to indicate that `event_id` and `question_id` paired together would be a unique index, so first we need to run:

```
ALTER TABLE `votes` ADD UNIQUE `event_question`(`event_id`, `question_id`);
```

This will give us a unique index which will allow us to then run:

```
INSERT INTO `votes` (`event_id`, `question_id`, `selected`, `user_id`) VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE selected='1,2,3';
```

This will insert the new row if a vote for a particular `event_id` and `question_id` are not found.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides a handy "`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`" clause (also known as "upsert"). I think this should work:

```
INSERT INTO `votes` (`event_id`, `question_id`, `selected`, `user_id`) VALUES
    (1, 2, 3, 4)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;
```

You'll need to make sure there's a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(event_id, question_id)`.